# Swift Transferring data to the first view by pressing the "Back" button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

> Hello friends .  Navigation control to the second screen. I need to go
>   to the one screen with the button(Sonucları Listele) on the second screen and I have to
>   make the number on the first screen to "2"

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAsaE.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMX59.png)

First View

```
class KonularViewController: UIViewController {

    var number : Int?

    @IBAction func barButtonKonuEkle(_ sender: Any) {
        let childViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KonuEkleViewController") as! KonuEkleViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(childViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Second View

```
class AramaViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn1.isSelected = true
    }

    @IBAction func btnListele(_ sender: Any) {
      //First View "Number" variable on the first screen will be 2
    }

    @IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton) {

        if sender.titleLabel?.text == "En Yeniler"
        {
        btn1.isSelected = true
        btn2.isSelected = false
        }
        else
        {
        btn2.isSelected = true
        btn1.isSelected = false
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't see a number in your views and it's a bit confusing on what you want to achieve. If you want to increase the number before you push your UIViewController you can just simply increment the number before you push it?

Comment: Do you want to set `FirstViewController`'s `number` to 2 when `AramaViewController`'s `btnListele` is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy would be to have a 3rd class that is your Model, which can hold state.

```
class Model {
   static let shared = Model()
   var count: Int = 1
}

class AramaViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction fund btnListele(_ sender: Any) {
      Model.shared.count += 1
      //First View "Number" variable on the first screen will be 2
}

class KonularViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
        numberView.text = "\(Model.shared.count)"  //display your number here
    }
}
```

### Another Option

Reach back in the Navigation Controller View Controllers array to the previous view and set a property.  This is a bit more fragile.

```
class KonularViewController: UIViewController {
    var count: Int = 1
    override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
        numberView.text = "\(count)"  //display your number here
    }
}

class AramaViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction fund btnListele(_ sender: Any) {
      let numberOfViews = navigationController.viewControllers.count
      if count > 1, let previousViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[numberOfViews-2] as? KonularViewController 
      previousViewController.count += 1
      //First View "Number" variable on the first screen will be 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming KonularViewController identifier is "KonularViewController".
In AramaViewController:

```
@IBAction func btnListele(_ sender: Any) {
      //First View "Number" variable on the first screen will be 2
      let konularViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KonularViewController") as! KonularViewController
      konularViewController.number = 2
      navigationController?.pushViewController(childViewController, animated: true)
}
```